# HQL JOIN involving multiple associations

Tags: java, hibernate

I have three entities with relation `UserDetails` hasmany `FiledTask` and `Task` hasMany `FiledTask`. All I want is list of `FiledTask` of particular `User`

For UserDetails:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="user",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
Collection<FiledTask> filedTasks = new ArrayList<FiledTask>();
```

And for Tasks I have

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="task")
Collection<FiledTask> filedTasks = new ArrayList<FiledTask>();
```

And FiledTask looks like

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(nullable = false, name = "taskId")
private Tasks task;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(nullable = false, name = "userId")
private UserDetails user;
```

I have tried

```
query = session.createQuery("from Tasks as tasks inner join tasks.filedTasks as files with files.user = :user");
query.setParameter("user", user); //user is UserDetails instance
```

But I am getting error clause can only reference columns in the driving table, means FiledTask can't userId for comparision?

```
with clause can only reference columns in the driving table [from com.akhi.app.cdm.Tasks as tasks inner join tasks.filedTasks as files with files.user = :user]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the FiledTasks of a given user, then the easiest thing to do is

```
UserDetails user = session.find(UserDetails.class, userId);
Collection<FiledTask> filesTasks = user.getFiledTasks();
```

Using HQL, it would be

```
select f from FiledTask f where f.user = :user
```

If what you want is in fact the tasks of a given user, then the query would simply be

```
select t from Tasks t
inner join t.filedTasks filedTask
where filedTask.user = :user
```

Note that the entity `Tasks` shouldbe named `Task`. An instance represents a single task, and not multiple ones.

Comment: thanks for response,Since I want multiple attributes from different tables I need to use JOIN.The Last query works fine, But it would be great if You could tell me the issue with my command.

Comment: The problem is that you're using `with` instead of using `where`.

Comment: I have used "with", to provide extra join conditions, The problem is I can not use the "user" field in this case however I could use other attributes of fileTask and by using "with" it runs fine. Seems like we can not use instance based comparison in this case.Also Can you advice some links that can brush up my HQL skills

Comment: Nope, sorry. Experience will brush up your skills.

Answer (score 5):

OK, looks like there is a bug in Hibernate

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-2772

I think in your case what you need to do is

```
query = session.createQuery("from Tasks as tasks inner join tasks.filedTasks as files with files.user.id = :userId");
query.setParameter("userId", user.id);
```

Hope this helps somebody.  I spend several hours on this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using a MySql (Inno) DB plus my dialect class derived from Hibernate's `MySQL5InnoDBDialect` - class.

I had to override the `supportsRowValueConstructorSyntax-method` and let it return `false` as MySQLDialect (which is the base class of MySQL5InnoDBDialect) returns `true`.

```
@Override
public boolean supportsRowValueConstructorSyntax() {
    return false;
}
```

Doing this, hibernate does not use the object reference (in your case `.user`) in order to create a tuple for the comparison. I hope, this will help.